# How to integrate Maven in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

Tags: maven, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to use Maven in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 version. I installed the maven plugin through check for updates. But I see the maven extension as "Developer Preview" version while installing. After installing the plugin, I can see maven option available in JDeveloper.

I tried to create a fusion web application and created pom.xml for the project. But it is creating an empty pom with only Model dependency and the compiler plugin. Default ADF libraries are not being added to the pom.xml.

I installed the JDeveloper 11.1.2.0.0 version and did the same. Here all the default ADF libraries that will come with fusion web application are created automatically in pom.xml.

Is Maven is supported completely in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 version ? Or do we have any other way to add the ADF Libraries in pom.xml. ?

I am struggling with this from one week. Can you please suggest me on this.

Regards,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You are using an 11g R1 release while JDev 11.1.2.0.0 is 11g R2. And then this comes into play:

> With JDeveloper 11gR2 you can use Maven 2 as your build engine, before
>   11gR2 you could download a plugin which did not work great because all
>   the required Oracle libraries which were not available in a public
>   repository. So you had no choice to add them manually to a Maven
>   Repository before you can use Maven.

Source: http://biemond.blogspot.be/2011/06/building-with-maven-in-jdeveloper-11gr2.html

Side note: You won't be able to compile your application using maven on a server without JDeveloper installed on it because Oracle doesn't provide a maven repository containing the ADF libraries (an option is to add the ADF libs to your own repo).